# Hide div if it will have an image with specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to hide external `div` If it will have an image with specific class. For example

```
<div class="slide">
  <img class="hidden" src="">
<div>
<div class="slide">
  <img class="shown" src="">
<div>
```

I want to hide `div` only that has hidden class.

Comment: You should give us an example of what you tried so we have a point of reference and also to help others if they have similar issues.

Comment: CSS has no parent selector so you can't do anything to an ancestor element based on a descendant element, so you'd need a JavaScript solution. Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: Next time please take care with the tags. If you allow JS then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector is no longer a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery you can do the following:

```
$(function() {
     $(‘.hidden’).parent().hide()
})
```

The middle line selects the parent of the DOM element and hides it. Wrapping the code within an anonymous function wrapped within the jQuery function delays execution of the code until the DOM is ready to be manipulated.